# How can I present a modal view on top of a tab bar controller?

Tags: ios

I made one button on the navigation bar. I made it to modal view. But the problem is I can't bring this modal view on the top of the tab bar. What should I do?

In addition, I have used storyboard's segue to present the modal view.

[Enter to see storyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZU1J.png)

[Enter to see simulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbIA0.png)

Comment: Can you describe more about what you done?. Post the screenshot of your storyboard.

Comment: GoCrazy, I have already added storyboard's image and simulator's image to describe.
As you see in the simulator's picture, tab bar is on top of the modal view. I want to show it below the modal view as other components. What should I do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the screenshots, but it seems like what you want is for the tab bar to become greyed out just like the background of the view inside the `UITabBarController`?

Where are you presenting the modal view from? If view controller A is inside your tab bar controller, then presenting the modal view from A will result in the tab bar not getting grayed out. If you present from the tab bar controller, it should do what you want.

In the presenting view controller's code, instead of

```
present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
```

try using

```
tabBarController?.present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
```

(Where `modalViewController` and `completion` are whatever you mean to use for these arguments, of course.)

If you are using a segue to present the modal controller, then the same concept applies. Move the segue to the tab bar controller and then perform it on the tab bar controller from the presenting view controller.

```
tabBarController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifier", sender: tabBarController)
```

Comment: If using a segue,  the segue should be from the `tabBarController` in the storyboard. Link from here to your modal view controller, not the view controller that is in one of the tabs.

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use the `modalPresentationStyle` of your view controller and set it to `fullScreen` or `overFullScreen` and this will automatically hide the tab bar, whether the view controller is presented from the tab bar or not.

Swift 4 example:

```
presentedVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
```

You can check the documentation for more information: *[UIModalPresentationStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle)*