# Present ViewController from TabBarController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I need to open ReportViewController from tabbar modally. How i can do that? I have this TabBarConfigurator:

```
import UIKit

final class TabBarConfigurator {

    // MARK: - Private property

    private let allTab: [TabBarModel] = [.explore, .feed, .report, .favorite, .profile]

    // MARK: - Internal Methods

    func configure() -> UITabBarController {
        return getTabBarController()
    }
}

// MARK: - Private Methods

private extension TabBarConfigurator {

    func getTabBarController() -> UITabBarController {
        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
        tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(named: "Green")
        tabBarController.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(named: "DarkGrey")
        tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = .white
        tabBarController.viewControllers = getViewControllers()
        return tabBarController
    }

    func getViewControllers() -> [UIViewController] {
        var viewControllers = [UIViewController]()
        allTab.forEach { tab in
            let controller = getCurrentViewController(tab: tab)
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tab.title, image: tab.image, selectedImage: tab.selectedImage)
            controller.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
            controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            controller.title = tab.title
            controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Background")
            viewControllers.append(navigationController)
        }
        return viewControllers
    }

    func getCurrentViewController(tab: TabBarModel) -> UIViewController {
        switch tab {
        case .explore:
            return ExploreViewController()
        case .feed:
            return ActivityViewController()
        case .report:
            return ReportViewController()
        case .favorite:
            return FavoritesViewController()
        case .profile:
            return ProfileViewController()
        }
    }
}
```

And SceneDelegate

```
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        runMainFlow()
        runLaunchScreen()
    }
    
    func runMainFlow() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.window?.rootViewController = TabBarConfigurator().configure()
            // Set the navigation bar title color
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "DarkGrey") ?? .black]
        }
    }
    
}
```

This is how it looks now.
[image: This is how it looks now]

But i wand to present it modally .pageSheet. How i can do it? I tried if .report inside getViewController function, but nothing happened.

```
    func getTabBarController() -> UITabBarController {
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(named: "Green")
    tabBarController.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(named: "DarkGrey")
    tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = .white
    tabBarController.viewControllers = getViewControllers(to: tabBarController)
    return tabBarController
}

func getViewControllers(to tabBarController: UITabBarController) -> [UIViewController] {
    var viewControllers = [UIViewController]()
    for tab in allTab {
        let controller = getCurrentViewController(tab: tab)
        if tab == .report {
            controller.title = tab.title
            controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Background")
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tab.title, image: tab.image, selectedImage: tab.selectedImage)
            controller.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
            navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
            tabBarController.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            viewControllers.append(navigationController)
        }
        if tab == .explore {
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tab.title, image: tab.image, selectedImage: tab.selectedImage)
            controller.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
            controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            controller.title = tab.title
            controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Background")
            viewControllers.append(navigationController)
        }
        if tab == .favorite {
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tab.title, image: tab.image, selectedImage: tab.selectedImage)
            controller.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
            controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            controller.title = tab.title
            controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Background")
            viewControllers.append(navigationController)
        }
        if tab == .feed {
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tab.title, image: tab.image, selectedImage: tab.selectedImage)
            controller.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
            controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            controller.title = tab.title
            controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Background")
            viewControllers.append(navigationController)
        }
        if tab == .profile {
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tab.title, image: tab.image, selectedImage: tab.selectedImage)
            controller.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
            controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            controller.title = tab.title
            controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Background")
            viewControllers.append(navigationController)
        }
    }
    return viewControllers
}
```

This is how it looks after my changes: [image]

And this is how it should look like, after tapping on report tab in tabbar [image]

Thank you all for answers!

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594465/how-can-i-present-a-modal-view-on-top-of-a-tab-bar-controller

Comment: Would it be correct to say that your actual goal is to have the Report tab to appear full screen anytime the tab is selected?

Comment: @HangarRash yes

Comment: And then what? How can users switch tabs with the Reports screen covering everything? What should happen when the user dismisses the Report screen? Should some other tab be automatically selected? If so, which one? Your question needs to be updated with all of these details.